# Scikit learn LinearSVC

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I'm using LinearSVC for document classification. For example the simple thing of SVM(Support Vector Machine) work is to separate data by Hyper-plane, for example data to be class A if a **value** < -1 and B for > 1, my question is how to show that **value** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [LinearSVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) documentation, visit the `Attributes` section. 'Showing that value' in your case means obtaining the coefficients and intercepts. LinearSVC returns `coef_` and `intercept_` which is what you need.

Comment: thanks !, im newbie with svm, i have 1 more question i have intercept value [-0.6766424  -0.67620787 -0.26330661 -0.92203303 -0.84416322 -0.604125  ] this is representation of my class right?
and 1 more question, 1 of all my coef is -1.13093621e-01, how to this liniearsvc assign this -1.13093621e-01 to one of my class ?